# Height text in cell word Interop

Tags: ms-word, office-interop

I have a cell height that is set to **fixed**, but sometimes my text in my cell exceeds... 
 I would like to know if it is possible to know the height of my text or the coordinates of the border of my text so if I know it I could reduce the size of my characters according on the height of my cell. 
 
[image]

What have I tried ? `w.GetPoint` but word is not visible when I do the data processing and the coordinates of my range are always equal to 0 , I try `Range.Information` Property too with `wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary` but I don’t know if I’m going in the right direction

Comment: Since Word relies heavily on its dynamic layout of a document at run-time, based on the current environment and printer-driver, determining this kind of thing without the document being visible is chancy, at best. You should consider making the window visible and then perhaps minimizing it...

Comment: Beyond that, *theorectically* it's possible to calculate the amount of vertical space a line in the font requires (although every font is different even when the same font size is used!). Add to that paragraph spacing before and after and any addition to the line spacing (if any), multiply by the number of lines/paragraphs - and you can *approximate* the vertical height. But there's no formula or hard-and-fast rule you can use. If you know a particular font is going to be used and a specific style, you'll have a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister. **'STACK OVERFLOW'** It is one and only line and not two separates words ,Word takes care of trimming my line according to the width of my cell. If I understand your second comment , you are suggesting to me to calculate the number of lines, but according to my explanation I did not know it. Have you another idea?